# mobile adaptive tables on grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a table built on grid. And I want to make this table adaptive. Adaptive for mobile devices. I do not know how I can do this using a grid-based table. Please tell me how I can adapt it for mobile screens? auto-fill is not exactly what you need. It simply moves blocks down, similar to flex wrap. With display:table, this is easier. Help me please.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.table_unit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.table_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <input type="submit" class="log_button_replace" value="Simple button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its only going to shrink until certain width is reached. After that it will overflow horizontally. What else do you want?

Comment: I need to make the top names where "This is text" is written move to the left

Comment: I want to do like this, but only on the grid - https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a extra `p` element in `.table_content` element which will only be visible on small screens. Add a media query which on smaller screens, will make `.table` element a grid of 1 column and `.table_column` element a grid of 2 columns.

**P.S.** In code snippet below, i have removed empty columns.

```css
.table p {
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.table_unit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px;
}

.responsive-header {
  display: none;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.table_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .table_unit {
    display: none;
  }
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .responsive-header {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .table_content,
  .responsive-header {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .table_content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p class="responsive-header">This is text</p>
    <input type="submit" class="log_button_replace" value="Simple button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Output on screens smaller or equal to `500px`

[image]

You could also achieve the desired layout using `:before` pseudo-element. This approach will help avoid duplicating html code

```css
.table p {
  margin: 0;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.table_unit {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px;
}

.table_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .table_unit {
    display: none;
  }
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .table_content div:before {
    content: 'This is text';
    background: #fafafa;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .table_content div:before,
  .table_content div {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .table_content {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <p>Simple text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <p>Simple text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <p>Simple text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <p>Simple text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <p>Simple text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <div>
      <input type="submit" class="log_button_replace" value="Simple button">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output on screens smaller or equal to `500px`

**P.S.** in second snippet, i have aligned text to the left on smaller screen size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting. Just add the below-given snippet in your code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
 .table{
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 }
  .table_unit,.table_content {
     padding: 0;  /* to remove padding */
     justify-content:left;
 }
}
```

Just reduce the `grid-template-columns` property repeat value on small devices using media queries.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.table_unit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.table_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .table_unit,
  .table_content {
    padding: 0;
    justify-content:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_unit">
    <p>This is text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <p>Simple text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_content">
    <input type="submit" class="log_button_replace" value="Simple button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to create 3 css files, each one for a screen size

then Add the following code to the html page in the `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1280px)" href="css/widescreen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)" href="css/middlescreen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="css/smallscreen.css">
```

**NOTE:** Very important when setting screen sizes in an HTML file. Start with largest size
Ranking from largest to smallest